# Dataset availability for automatic text summarization

Tags: dataset, nlp, automatic-summarization

I'm working on an automatic text summarization NLP problem and looking for a dataset with USA legal case reports similar to the [Australian legal case reports dataset in UCI repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Legal+Case+Reports).

Can you please refer me to any such dataset? I've not been able to find one up until now. It will also be great if you can point me to other industry-relevant datasets that can be used for automatic text summarization.